# Not getting second page data using python Request

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests, python-responses

I am trying to get movie reviews from Fandango website. Even when I hit the URL for the second page onwards of movie reviews for a particular movie I keep getting the first page. Do I need to send cookies with requests?

Below is my code snippet:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

baseUrl = 'https://www.fandango.com/movie-reviews'
req = Request(baseUrl, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
webpage = urlopen(req).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage, 'html.parser')

# Getting all the movie links from the first page
movieLinks = soup.find_all("a", class_='dark')

# Get reviews for every movie
for i in range(2):#len(movieLinks)
    try:
        movieName = movieLinks[i].text.replace(' Review', '')
        count = 1
        print('\n\n****** ' + movieName + ' ********\n\n')
        # Getting movie reviews from first 10
        for j in range(3):
            pageNum = j + 1;
            movieReviewUrl = movieLinks[i]['href'] + '?pn=' + str(pageNum)
            print('Hitting URL: ' + movieReviewUrl)
            revReq = Request(movieReviewUrl, headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
            revWebpage = urlopen(revReq).read()
            revSoup = BeautifulSoup(revWebpage, 'html.parser')
            revArr = revSoup.find_all("p", class_ = "fan-reviews__item-content")
            for k in range(len(revArr)):
                if len(revArr[k])>0:
                    print(str(count) + ' : ' + revArr[k].text)
                    count = count + 1
    except:
        print('Error for movie: ' + movieName)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/), it's much easier to handle such requests with it.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

baseUrl = 'https://www.fandango.com/movie-reviews'
# req = Request(baseUrl, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
webpage = requests.get(baseUrl).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage, 'html.parser')

# Getting all the movie links from the first page
movieLinks = soup.find_all("a", class_='dark')

# Get reviews for every movie
for i in range(2):#len(movieLinks)
 try:
    movieName = movieLinks[i].text.replace(' Review', '')
    count = 1
    print('\n\n****** ' + movieName + ' ********\n\n')
    # Getting movie reviews from first 10
    for j in range(3):
        pageNum = j + 1;
        movieReviewUrl = movieLinks[i]['href'] + '?pn=' + str(pageNum)
        print('Hitting URL: ' + movieReviewUrl)
        # revReq = Request(movieReviewUrl, headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
        # revWebpage = urlopen(revReq).read()
        revWebpage = requests.get(movieReviewUrl).text
        revSoup = BeautifulSoup(revWebpage, 'html.parser')
        revArr = revSoup.find_all("p", class_ = "fan-reviews__item-content")
        print(len(revArr))
        for k in range(len(revArr)):
            if len(revArr[k])>0:
                print(str(count) + ' : ' + revArr[k].text)
                count = count + 1
except:
    print('Error for movie: ' + movieName)
```

When you run it, you can see that revArr is returning 0, so please check "fan-reviews__item-content".

Comment: I had used Requests earlier, it didn't work so I tried changing it to requests. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: Are you sure that the url you are generating is correct?

Comment: Ohh yeah.. for that very purpose I printed the URL as a log everytime. Can you please try running the snippet on your machine? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I tried with Requests now. Check the line revSoup.find_all("p", class_ = "fan-reviews__item-content"), it doesn't return anything despite having loaded the correct site (e.g. check it with prettify()). The script itself runs without errors with Requests (you might have to upgrade openssl).

Comment: Sorry if I am not getting you here, but that line returned me the reviews correctly from the first page!